# How to access the property function within a function object javascript

Tags: javascript, function

the following is the code I have written

```
var nums = [1, 5, 4, 2, 3];
var sortedNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var sorter = function MakeSorter() {
    'sortNums': function(nums) {
        return this.nums.sort();
    };
};

QUnit.test("Numeric list can be sorted", function(assert) {
    var sorted = sorter.sortNums(nums);
    assert.deepEqual(sorted, sortedNums, "Passed!");
});
```

My supposition are as follows:

1. sorter is a function object referencing MakeSorter() function
2. sortNums is a property of MakeSorter which turns out to be an object and hence has the function syntax

but it produces the error as expected ";" on the line where sortNums is declared.why?

Comment: The error is a syntax error, you can't just throw something that looks like an object literal property inside a function.

Comment: I can understand that @adeneo, what is the correct syntax then?

Comment: Either an object literal, not a function, or `this.sortNums = function(){..`

Comment: But why do you need an inner function at all, it's not like you're really using the outer function for anything ?

Comment: @DineshSashikanth http://pastebin.com/sH4fti3N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would set the property `sortNums` on `sorter` to the function that you provided.  However, I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do in accomplishing this and there may be a better way to design the behavior you're trying to accomplish.

```
  var nums = [1, 5, 4, 2, 3];
  var sortedNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  var sorter = function MakeSorter() {};
  sorter.sortNums = function(nums) {
      return this.nums.sort();
  };

  QUnit.test("Numeric list can be sorted", function(assert) {
      var sorted = sorter.sortNums(nums);
      assert.deepEqual(sorted, sortedNums, "Passed!");
  });
```

In short, your syntax error seems to be that you are mixing up a function body declaration with an object literal.  The statements inside a function body (between the `{` and `}`) are executed when the function is called.  You cannot define properties on the function by adding them in object literal syntax `{ prop : value }`.

```
var sorter = {
  sortNums: function(nums) {
      return this.nums.sort();
  }
};
```

might be more along the lines of what you are looking for if sorter does not need to be callable.

Comment: `var sorter = function MakeSorter() {};` is *weird* syntax event though valid

Comment: It is valid syntax if recursion is desired but yes, extraneous in this case.

Comment: A javascript class seems unnecessary here. You could just define a bare `sortNums` function, or define it as an object `var sorter = {}` and the rest would make sense. If you're going to make it a class, you should follow the pattern properly. Eg, `function MakeSorter() {};`, then define the member function on the prototype `MakeSorter.prototype.sortNums = function...` and instantiate using the `new` operator `var sorter = new MakeSorter()`;

Comment: Since `sortNums` doesn't rely on the state of the class, it could be "statically" assigned as a property of the class constructor.  The constructed instances will not have the method inherited but static functions should be invoked statically anyhow.  The design of this likely relies on your coding convention

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant to use `this`:

```
var nums = [1, 5, 4, 2, 3];
var sortedNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var MakeSorter = function () {
    this.sortNums = function(nums) {
        return this.nums.sort();
    }
};

var sorter = new MakeSorter();

QUnit.test("Numeric list can be sorted", function(assert) {
    var sorted = sorter.sortNums(nums);
    assert.deepEqual(sorted, sortedNums, "Passed!");
});
```

You seem to of got the idea that in JavaScript, functions *are* object, but slightly different. What you are trying to make is kind of like a JavaScript class. You are making function as regular, not an object. In order to *add* a function to a function use `this`. That's short for:

```
var MakeSorter = function () {
   //...
}

MakeSorter.sortNums = function (nums) {
    //...
}
```